# Gravar video com framework AVfoundation e salvar na galeria do iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou criando um app pra IOS 8 que utiliza a câmera frontal para gravar vídeo do usuário até que uma certa ação seja chamada, e ao fim salvar na galeria.

Porém até o momento só consegui fazer isso com foto(tira sucessivas fotos e salva na galeria) e não com vídeo.

Estou usando a biblioteca AVfoundation.

Alguém pode dar alguma luz?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar de alguns passos utilizando o `UIImagePickerController`:

## Frameworks

Importar os frameworks necessários em *Linked Frameworks and Libraries*:

- **AssetsLibrary.framework**
- **MobileCoreServices.framework**

E no seu arquivo de cabeçalho:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

## Delegates

Será preciso 2 *delegates*, ambos para o *Controller* que será aberto para a captura do vídeo. Também no seu arquivo de cabeçalho, inclua os dois:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

## Definindo propriedades e abrindo a câmera

Aqui você define algumas propriedades da câmera e a forma como este `Controller` será aberto, sendo um "modal" e após verificar a existência da câmera no aparelho:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [cameraPicker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    [cameraPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [cameraPicker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil]];
    [cameraPicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [cameraPicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    [cameraPicker setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Essas propriedades você mesmo pode definir da forma como for utilizar. Baseado na sua pergunta, já incluí para abrir a câmera frontal com os controles habilitados.

## Salvando o vídeo na biblioteca

E por fim, no método de *delegate* `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, você receberá todas as informações e salvar o vídeo em sua biblioteca:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]) {
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        BOOL compatible = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum([videoURL path]);

        if (compatible) {
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

            if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL]) {
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL
                                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                                [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                            }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note que aqui eu não incluí os `else`, mas você pode fazer por aí, que indicam se não houve captura do vídeo, não há compatibilidade e não é possível salvar na biblioteca do aparelho, seja porque não foi autorizado ou qualquer outro motivo.

E esse outro *delegate*, apenas para fechar a câmera caso a ação seja cancelada:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

É isso. Fiz um projeto bem simples aqui, se houver necessidade eu posso disponibilizar para download e você testar daí.